# Explaining if the terms 'Father' and 'son of G-d' are used in Jewish books

Tags: hebrew, theology, language, kerovim-close-relatives

Within Judaism and their books, was it a custom of the time to refer to G-d as the Father?

Is the term son of G-d used in any of your works?   I heard this term is used to refer to an observant person or respected person.

Can you please elaborate on the above and provide some verses if possible.

Comment: What is "the time"? Judaism's books have been written for the past three thousand years.

Comment: I mean whenever they were recorded, in that time period, where these terms/phrases used and if so what was the true meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Are you asking specifically about biblical texts, or all of them?

Comment: re respected person, I think you are thinking of Man of God: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2690.htm

Answer (score 3):

Check out for the use of Father:

[Isaiah 63:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1063.htm#16) and [64:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1064.htm#7).

[1 Chronicles 29:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a29.htm#10)

[Deuteronomy 32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0532.htm): 6

[Psalms 68:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2668.htm#6)

[Malachi 1:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2401.htm#6)

for a start.

And now [Jeremiah 3:19](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16000#showrashi=true).

Comment: thanks exactly what I wanted in terms of references.  I guess the Hellenistic Roman influence took these words to another level.

Comment: Wait, is there an example of 'son of god'?

Comment: @user1361315 I didn't look for 'son of god'.

Comment: @user1361315, see the comment on my answer.

Comment: @user1361315 I have added a quote from Jeremiah, as promised.

Answer (score 2):

God is often called Jews' "father" in Jewish texts, most famously in liturgy. (We ask that he have mercy on us as a father has on his children.) Occasionally, we're called his sons, too. This is all, of course, metaphorical: God has not physically sired anyone, being nonphysical himself.

Comment: This site http://drazin.com/?6._The_%22Son_of_G-D%22_MYTH has a list of people referred to as a "son" of God.

Comment: @Danno, thanks. It seems such a list would make a good answer to the question.

Comment: can you cite a verse in which a prophet is referred to as God's son? The only places I can think of where children of God are even mentioned is in Job, referring to angels, and in the Pentateuch somewhere, referring to the nation of Israel as a whole.

Comment: @BabySeal... thinking about it now, I think I was wrong. "_Elohim_" is used for various people, but "son of God" isn't that I'm aware of. I'll remove that paragraph. Thanks for catching me on it.